# What is this pest attacking a fig tree?

Tags: pest-control, pests, figs, scale

I have a fig tree that is covered in these strange pests. They appear to be live organisms, but they don't move.

What could these be and how can I deal with them?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The brown dots are an advanced infestation of [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect).  This is not the [fig scale](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/orn/scales/fig_wax_scale.htm) which looks pinkish and has an unusual shape but a more common variety.  This is a common pest and regardless of the species control is the same. The white dots could be young scale or whitefly attracted by the sticky sap the scale excretes. You can learn more from [this link](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=scale):

- mix five ml of dish soap in one litre of water, a few ml of baby oil or mineral oil or isopropyl alcohol is optional.
- rinse a disposable cloth or soft scrubby in the mix
- gently scrub off the scale from all surfaces (branches and leaves, top and bottom)
- repeat at five to seven day intervals for at least three times